# angularjs data inconsistency

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use a value from a parent scope in a directive but it looks like I'm dealing in quantum physics territory: If I look at the content I want from the scope it seems to vanish

```
console.log($scope.bundle); // array

console.log($scope.bundle[0]); // [] (empty array.. should not be)

window.test = $scope.bundle;
in console: test[0];         //{...} //has content
```

Comment: Does your directive have an isolated scope?  I believe that the Chrome debugger console will show you the 'array' data at the time it is expanded, not the time it is output with console.log(). Are you sure you actually have data at the time you're trying to access it?  Can you provide more context and/or a Plunker?  I believe it is impossible to help you based on the code sample provided.

Comment: looks like `$scope.bundle` is populated asynchronously... but we can't tell precisely without seeing the code